# Remove profile picture from fan page converted from private profile

Tags: facebook-pages

I merged my private profile to a fan page.  How can I remove my profile picture album off my fan page without also deleting it from my personal profile?

Answer (score 1):

You had to do this before converting the profile into page. Once you change the privacy of your image "Only me", it won't publish on page.

Now I don't think there is any option available other than deleting the image.